# joining all cell value between ascending range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, concatenation

I am trying to figure out how to join every cell (normal text) in the D column between the range I have set up in the A column. While searching I came across variations of the concatenate, textjoin and other functions but could not seem to find the right option.

There are around 8000 values in my file(ID value in column A) so it should be automatically filled and not manual. since it would take weeks to complete...

i've added a visual representation of the problem

[image]

The solution would be to have all cells selected in column D between the value '1' and '2' in column A and joined togheter in the E column in the row where the the cell in the A column isn't blank.
I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Not sure what version of excel you have, but you could try something along this array formula lines `=IF(A1<>"",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,OFFSET(B1,,,MAX(($A$1:$A$6=A1+1)*(ROW($B$1:$B$6)))-1,1)),"")`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post an expected output sample?

Comment: the If formula didn't work. i got the #value as return.
Thanks for the welcome. the ideal output would be in E2 = text1, text2, text3
the blanks should be ignored.. the problem lies in the fact the range is always different between the values in the A column...

Comment: What about the empty cells (D5:D7 range in your example)? Will they be escaped? Is there any separator necessary when the values in column D are joined? Can you post an example of the wished string to be returned? Will it be "text1text2text3" as you let us understand,  or "text1,text2,text3" rom your first example range? Will this string be somehow processed in a later phase? Now I could see that there is a separator (", "). What about the blanc cells? Would the string be OK being like this: "text1, text2, text3, , "

Comment: The blank cells should be ignored. If that would be to difficult it wouldn't be aproblem since i can always use a forumla with RIGHT to delete the last comma's

Comment: @Bart Meeuwes: Please test my code answer and confirm that it does what you need.

Comment: @BartMeeuwes the IF formula is an array, so you need to use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to use it.  You will also need to adjust it for your data, I had dummy data in A1:B6 and it worked as requested.  So my B column will be your D column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, please. It should be very fost, using arrays and returns the built strings at once at the end:

```
Sub testJoinBetweenLimits()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arrInit As Variant, arrFin As Variant
  Dim strInit As String, i As Long, j As Long, refRow As Long
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
    arrInit = sh.Range("A2:D" & sh.Range("D" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).value
    ReDim arrFin(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arrInit, 1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrInit, 1)
        If arrInit(i, 1) <> "" Then strInit = arrInit(i, 4): refRow = i: j = i + 1
        Do While arrInit(j, 1) = ""

            If arrInit(j, 4) <> "" Then
                strInit = strInit & ", " & arrInit(j, 4)
            Else
                arrFin(1, j) = Empty
            End If
            j = j + 1
                If j >= sh.Range("D" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Then
                    arrFin(1, refRow) = strInit
                    ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 1, 1 To refRow)
                    GoTo Ending
                End If
        Loop
        i = j - 1
        arrFin(1, refRow) = strInit: strInit = "": j = 0
    Next i
Ending:
    sh.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrFin, 2), 1).value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin)
End Sub
```